# Apache 2: www.domain pointing to the wrong index

Tags: indexing, configuration, dns, apache2

I am encountering a very strange behaviour with Apache 2 that I cant seem to solve. Essentially I have a domain, lets call it domain1.

http://domain1.ovh points to the correct folder.

http://www.domain1.ovh points to the folder of another website I am hosting with Apache 2. (Which is not intended, both addresses are supposed to point to the same folder and show the same page.)

I cant seem to find a way to fix this problem. I apologize if you find this question to be a repeat but I read all the suggested questions and none helped me.

Here is my Apache 2 configuration file:

```
        <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName celtiberianproductions.ovh
        ServerAlias celtiberianproductions.ovh www.celtiberianproductions.ovh
        DocumentRoot /var/www/celtiberianproductions.ovh
        <Directory />
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/celtiberianproductions.ovh>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/celtiberianproductions.ovh-error.log
        LogLevel error
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/celtiberianproductions.ovh-access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

I must also add that in my domain provider control panel I am pointing both domain1.ovh and www.domain1.ovh to the IP address of the VPS machine I have with an A link.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is?

Comment: I added further info to clear things up. Both addresses are supposed to show the same folder, and not different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache 2 configuration seems OK but your domain names point to different ip addresses:

https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/domain1.ovh

```
;QUESTION
domain1.ovh. IN A
;ANSWER
domain1.ovh. 3599 IN A 51.254.133.96
```

https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/www.domain1.ovh

```
;QUESTION
www.domain1.ovh. IN A
;ANSWER
www.domain1.ovh. 3598 IN A 213.186.33.5
```